# nssplitview programmatically add nsview on top

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nssplitview

I am trying to programmatically add a NSView over a NSSplitView (to cover it). Every attempt to do this has resulted in it being added into the NSSplitview as an extra subview.
Can anyone please help?

Codes:

```
InfoTrainView *myView = [[[InfoTrainView alloc] initWithFrame: aFrame] autorelease];
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"InfoTrainView" owner:myView]; 
[self.windowController.splitViewBase addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: let NSSlipt view is A, your view is B, so are you getting another view as C ?

Comment: I always end up with the Splitview with an additional subview. It originally had 3 horiz. subviews, and it gets a fourth subview (view B).

Comment: The splitview base address from IB is self.windowController.splitViewBase. `InfoTrainView *myView = [[[InfoTrainView alloc] initWithFrame: aFrame] autorelease];
 [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"InfoTrainView" owner:myView];
 [self.windowController.splitViewBase addSubview:myView];
`. I have experimented with placing the InfoTrainView at super level, but this did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add your new view as a child to the NSSplitView's *superview* (ie. parent). This way it becomes a *sibling to the NSSplitView* and can cover it. Your current method makes the new view a child of the split view, which then sets itself up as splitting four ways.

```
NSView* parentView = [self.windowController.splitViewBase superview];
if (parentView)
    [parentView addSubview:myView];
```

`parentView` above should get you the "content view" that is the default NSView inside of an NSWindow, which IB placed the NSSplitView inside. If `parentView == nil`, you can try manually adding an NSView to the window first, then putting your NSSplitView inside of that.

On a side note, your *question* answered my own question - how to programmatically add to the views split inside of an NSSplitView! Thanks :)